# VBA Selection.InsertFile additionally NewLine at the end

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to import some word documents as footer with the following code. Unfortunately, the selection.insertfile function inserts additionally a new line at the end of the footer. Is it possible to remove it? I've tried many things, without a result.

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()

   'Fußzeile aktualisieren
    Call UpdateFooter
    
End Sub

'Fußzeile für alle Seiten editieren
Sub UpdateFooter()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document, oSec As Word.section, rng As Word.Range
    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

    For Each oSec In oDoc.Sections
        Set rng = oSec.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range
        AddFooterToRange rng
        'oSec.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Font.Size = 5
        
        Set rng = oSec.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        AddFooterToRange rng
        'oSec.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Font.Size = 5
        
        Set rng = oSec.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range
        AddFooterToRange rng
        'oSec.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range.Font.Size = 5
        
    Next oSec
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

'Fußzeilendatei einfügen
Private Sub AddFooterToRange(rng As Word.Range)
    With rng
         .InsertFile "...fusszeile.docx"
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the last paragraph in the footer.

```
Private Sub AddFooterToRange(rng As Word.Range)
    With rng
         .InsertFile "...fusszeile.docx"
         .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```